# How to change colors of mean and error bar using stat_summary for grouped variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, errorbar

I was wondering if it is possible to change the colors of the error bars and the means for each group of my dataset. I want one color for each level of the var_col (so, two colors), but I want the mean and the error bar in black.

```
var_y = rnorm(n  = 100, mean = 3)
var_x = c("A", "B")
var_col = c(rep("a", times = 50), rep("b", times = 50))

df <- data.frame(var_x, var_y, var_col)

ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x=var_x,y=var_y, col = var_col))+
  geom_point(alpha=.3, position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, geom="errorbar", width = 0,
               position = position_dodge(.2), 
               fun.args = list(mult=1))+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom='point',
               position = position_dodge(.2), size = 3)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySC9g.png)

I tried to change the color as an argument in stat_summary, but it gives me only two error bars instead of four.
I also tried to give a vector of four colors in stat_summary, but it gives the message: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2)

```
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x=var_x,y=var_y, col = var_col))+
  geom_point(alpha=.3, position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, geom="errorbar", width = 0,
               position = position_dodge(.2),  color = 'black',
               fun.args = list(mult=1))+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom='point',
               position = position_dodge(.2), size = 3)
```

I also tried to plot the mean with geom_point() and the error bar with_geom_errorbar, but the levels stay to close to each other, because I cannot give more space to the errorbars

```
    library(dplyr)
    description <- df |> 
      group_by(var_x, var_col) |> 
         summarise(mean_groups = mean(var_y),
            sd_groups = sd(var_y))

    ggplot()+
      geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x=var_x,y=var_y, colour = var_col), alpha=.3, position =  position_dodge(.5)) +
      geom_point(description, mapping = aes(x=var_x,y=mean_groups, colour = var_col), position = position_dodge(.5)) +
      geom_errorbar(description, mapping = aes(x = var_x, ymin=mean_groups - sd_groups, ymax=mean_groups + sd_groups), position = position_dodge2(), width = 0.1) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgreen", "darkred"))`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using the `group` aesthetic in both of your summaries:

```r
library(ggplot2)
var_y = rnorm(n  = 100, mean = 3)
var_x = c("A", "B")
var_col = c(rep("a", times = 50), rep("b", times = 50))

df <- data.frame(var_x, var_y, var_col)

ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x=var_x,y=var_y, col = var_col))+
  geom_point(alpha=.3, position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  stat_summary(mapping=aes(group=var_col), fun.data=mean_sdl, geom="errorbar", width = 0,
               position = position_dodge(.2),  color = 'black',
               fun.args = list(mult=1))+
  stat_summary(aes(group=var_col), fun = mean, geom='point',
               position = position_dodge(.2), size = 3, color="black")
```

[image]

Or using Axeman's suggestion:

```r
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x=var_x,y=var_y, col = var_col))+
  geom_point(alpha=.3, position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  stat_summary(mapping=aes(group=var_col), fun.data=mean_sdl, geom="pointrange",
               position = position_dodge(.2),  color = 'black',
               fun.args = list(mult=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Use `geom = "pointrange"` and you only need one `stat_summary`.